# How do I only get new documents from firebase using .onSnapshot when used with .limitToLast for pagination

Tags: firebase, pagination, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement a chat app with infinite scroll using Firebase.  The problem is that if I don't empty my messages array when a new message is added then they're duplicated.  If I empty the messages array then it doesn't keep the previous messages.

Here is the code:

```js
  getAllMessages(matchId: string) {
    this.chatSvc.getAllMessages(matchId)
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .limitToLast(5)
      .onSnapshot((doc) => {
        if (!doc.empty) {
          this.messages = [];
          doc.forEach((snap) => {
            this.messages.push({
              content: snap.data().content,
              createdAt: snap.data().createdAt,
              sendingUserId: snap.data().sendingUserId,
              receivingUserId: snap.data().receivingUserId
            });
          });
        } else {
          this.messages = [];
        }
      });
  }
```

And the chat service that returns the reference:

```js
  getAllMessages(matchId: string): firebase.firestore.CollectionReference<firebase.firestore.DocumentData> {
    return firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection(`matches`)
    .doc(`${matchId}`)
    .collection('messages');

  }
```

I'm pushing the messages from the collection in to a messages array.  If I don't add 'this.messages = []' then it will duplicate messages every time a new one is added to the collection.

How do I only get the new document from firebase with onSnapshot instead of it iterating through all of the collection again?  I only want the last message because I'm going to implement infinite scroll with another query that retrieves previous messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query will always return the last 5 result whenever a new entry that matches the condition occurs, which will create the duplicates. What you can do is to [listen to changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

```
getAllMessages(matchId: string) {
    this.chatSvc.getAllMessages(matchId)
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .limitToLast(5)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          // push only new documents that were added
          if(change.type === 'added'){
           this.messages.push(change.doc.data());
          }
        });
      });
  }
```